# C# WebBrowser Navigate freezes

Tags: c#, .net, web, browser

I need to scrape data from some web sites but I am currently stuck and unable to solve a serious problem.

When I login some of those web sites, user dashboard is opened in a new page. This is where the problem begins. I need to cancel opening a new page and instead, I should navigate to that URL in the same `WebBrowser` instance. I handle canceling of opening new page as below.

```
...
browser.AllowNavigation = true;
(browser.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1).NewWindow += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NewWindowEventHandler(HandleBrowserNewWindow);
...

protected virtual void HandleBrowserNewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed) { 
    Processed = true;
    browser.Navigate(URL);
}
```

`HandleBrowserNewWindow` method is called when `WebBrowser` tries to open a new page. However when I call `browser.Navigate(URL)` after the line I set `Processed` to `true`, `WebBrowser` does not navigate, moreover it freezes.

In order to debug, I assigned methods for the `WebBrowser`'s `Navigating` and `DocumentCompleted` delegates. The result is surprisingly ridicoulus. Here are the delegate methods:

```
protected void BrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doc Completed: {0}", e.Url);
}

protected void BrowserNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Navigating: {0}", e.Url);
}
```

And this is a block of code in which I use for automated login:

```
...
browser.Navigate(LoginURL);
...
HtmlElement helUsername = browser.Document.GetElementById("username");
HtmlElement helPassword = browser.Document.GetElementById("password");
HtmlElement helLoginButton = browser.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin");

helUsername.Focus();
helUsername.SetAttribute("value", LoginUser);
helUsername.InvokeMember("change");
helUsername.RemoveFocus();

await Task.Delay(50);

helPassword.Focus();
helPassword.SetAttribute("value", LoginPass);
helPassword.InvokeMember("change");
helPassword.RemoveFocus();

await Task.Delay(50);

helLoginButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Navigating: https://someurl.com/Login
Doc Completed: https://someurl.com/Login
Navigating: https://someurl.com/Login
Doc Completed: https://someurl.com/Login
Navigating: https://someurl.com/Dashboard
```

As you can see, Login page is navigated twice which I actually navigate once in code. In addition, `WebBrowser` tries to navigate to Dashboard but it can't reach further than `Navigating`. `WebBrowser` freezes there and document never gets completed.

Please help me to solve this issue. It is very important to me right now.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I have a feeling that the browser doesn't like being navigated while it's in the middle of a navigation (during the `NewWindow` event). I would try saving the URL and waiting for the process to complete to do the new navigation.

Comment: @Ahmet: Did Jacks feedback help?